# Unable to update the EntitySet 'ItemRankList' because it has a DefiningQuery and no <UpdateFunction> element exists

Tags: c#, linq

Any ideas why does the entity framework in LINQ gives following strange error:

> Unable to update the EntitySet 'ItemRankList' because it has a DefiningQuery and no  element exists in the  element to support the current operation.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Guess i should also ask the context... how are you using linq?

Do you have a **primary key** defined on the table ?

If not add the key and update the EF model.

Comment: Good.. Thanks for the replay! I fixed this issue!!!
Problem is that the composite Primary key is not set in the DB table where as the key are defined in the entity relations which causing this error.

As Nix stated, fixed by 2 steps..
> Creating the Composite P-Key 
> Updating the entity with new DB schema

Comment: I had a similar issue and even after updating my model to include the primary key, updating the model from the DB didn't seem to solve it. Deleting the entity from the model and re-adding it from the DB did sort it however. Yet another EF model not properly updating from the DB story!

Comment: Same problem, I didn't have the primary key set on the column in the table. Once I set the primary key, I updated the EF model and this fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with the accepted answer.
Just providing the reason behind it...

When EF mapping is done with a table which doesnot have Primary key, it is considered as a view & views being logical enity, cant be updated.

So either add the missing primary key in ur tables or consider them as View & dont perform any update operation on them.

Answer (score 0):

Add primary key, delete entity and add again in .edmx file. Clean and compile solution.