# Getting an error when trying to delete objects with Entity Framework 4

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I'm getting the following error when trying to delete objects in my database while using Entity Framework 4.

> "Unable to update the EntitySet 'SampleDetails' because it has a
>   DefiningQuery and no  element exists in the
>    element to support the current
>   operation."

It seems to be a common problem with lots of solutions on Google but nothing seems to work for me. The affected table has a composite primary key made up of three fields.

I have tried deleting the `<DefiningQuery>` elements but then I can't read the data from the database in the first place.

Comment: Any chance you'd post some code, so we can clearly see what you're doing?

Comment: Have you also seen this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2508464/284240 Is the composite Primary key   set in the  table and the entity model updated?

Comment: Thanks, I've tried refreshing my model and now I can't read anything from the DB. Looks like I may have deeper issues here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add primary key as a **separate column** like i.e. `SampleDetailsID` to SampleDetails.

Comment: I think that's the reason why. I also had the same problem but when I added new, separate ID column to table problem vanished.

Comment: Hi Adrian, you're probably right about the separate ID column but it looks like I have other issues with my DB. I need to address these first.